# Why a linear map with a negative double eigenvalue arising from the solution of a linear differential equation is proportional to the identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems

I'm trying to solve problem 3.2.5 from the book *A First Course in Dynamics* of B. Hasselblatt and A. Katok that says:

> Suppose a linear map with a double negative eigenvalue arises from the
> solution of a linear differential equation. Show that it is
> proportional to the identity.

I am assuming that I should take a $2\times 2$ matrix because the problem is from chapter 3: *Linear Maps and Linear Differential Equations*, that develops all content using $2\times 2$ matrices and because no other information about other posible eigenvalues is given.

Taking the $2\times 2$ matrix
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b\\\ c & d \end{bmatrix},$$
if $A$ has a repetead negative eivenlue $\lambda$, I can conclude from the characteristic polynomial that $\big[\mathrm{Tr}(A)\big]^2 - 4\det(A)$ must be cero, so $\lambda = \mathrm{Tr}(A)/2$ with $\mathrm{Tr}(A) < 0$.

But this is not enought to ensure that $A$ will be a diagonal matrix, and therefore, a matrix proportional to de identity. I can find non-diagonal $2\times 2$ matrices that have a reapeated negative eigenvalue. (In fact, I need to conclude something stronger: $a = d < 0$ and $b = c = 0$).

But I don't know how to obtain more assumptions to lead to those conclusions. I guess that it has someting to do with the part of the problem that says "Suppose a linear map [...] arises from the solution of a linear differential equation." But I don't get what that is saying to me. It implies that the matrix must be diagonlizable or something like that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You would have to look in the preceding pages of the book if that formulation is used elsewhere. For eigenvalues you need an endomorphism. One can of course compute eigenvalues of any square matrix, but here we have context, and thus can say if some domain vector space is the same as the target vector space or not. For instance, the solution of a linear DE maps initial values to the values at some fixed time linearly. If one identifies the state spaces at all time points, then this gives an endomorphism. But is this the one from the question?